# Why doesn't row data show up in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, row

I'm using Oracle database and I've created a test table "Table1" with a varchar column "column1". I ran the following loop to add some rows:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i in 1..10 LOOP
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COLUMN1) 
        VALUES (i);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

If I run 'select count(*) from table1' I get '10' as my result. However, in SQL Developer, nothing shows up. I can add rows manually and commit them to the database(these appear in SQL Developer), but I can't seem to view the ones created in sqlplus command line. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no COMMIT up there in your code.
By default SQL*Plus autocommit is off.
Data changes are not visible to other sessions until they are not commited.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I knew it had to be something simple